# GDAL/OGR (Python) GetGeomType() method returns integer, what is the matching geom type?

Tags: python, gdal, geometry, ogr, open-source-gis

When I use the GetGeomType() with GDAL/OGR it returns an integer. I want to know what geometry type each integer represents.

```py
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("FileGDB")
gdb = r"C:\Users\******\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
ds = driver.Open(gdb, 0)
input_lyr_name = "Birmingham_Burglaries_2016"
lyr = ds.GetLayerByName(input_lyr_name)
# access the schema info
lyr_def = lyr.GetLayerDefn()

print lyr_def.GetGeomType()
```

Output: 1

I already know an alternative way to get the geometry type as below, but I am interested to match integers to the correct geometry type. Is there a list somewhere?

```py
first_feat = lyr.GetFeature(1)
print first_feat.geometry().GetGeometryName()
```

Output: POINT

But this won't work on an empty dataset.

Comment: `print ogr.GeometryTypeToName(lyr_def.GetGeomType())`

Comment: @Luke smashing stuff. That will come in very handy.

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find the output variants of WKB types supported by GDAL here:

[OGC 06-103r4 "OpenGIS® Implementation Standard for Geographic information - Simple feature access - Part 1: Common architecture", v1.2.1](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355)

From §8.2.8 (page 66):

```
enum WKBGeometryType {
wkbPoint = 1,
wkbLineString = 2,
wkbPolygon = 3,
wkbTriangle = 17
wkbMultiPoint = 4,
wkbMultiLineString = 5,
wkbMultiPolygon = 6,
wkbGeometryCollection = 7,
wkbPolyhedralSurface = 15,
wkbTIN = 16
wkbPointZ = 1001,
wkbLineStringZ = 1002,
wkbPolygonZ = 1003,
wkbTrianglez = 1017
wkbMultiPointZ = 1004,
wkbMultiLineStringZ = 1005,
wkbMultiPolygonZ = 1006,
wkbGeometryCollectionZ = 1007,
wkbPolyhedralSurfaceZ = 1015,
wkbTINZ = 1016
wkbPointM = 2001,
wkbLineStringM = 2002,
wkbPolygonM = 2003,
wkbTriangleM = 2017
wkbMultiPointM = 2004,
wkbMultiLineStringM = 2005,
wkbMultiPolygonM = 2006,
wkbGeometryCollectionM = 2007,
wkbPolyhedralSurfaceM = 2015,
wkbTINM = 2016
wkbPointZM = 3001,
wkbLineStringZM = 3002,
wkbPolygonZM = 3003,
wkbTriangleZM = 3017
wkbMultiPointZM = 3004,
wkbMultiLineStringZM = 3005,
wkbMultiPolygonZM = 3006,
wkbGeometryCollectionZM = 3007,
wkbPolyhedralSurfaceZM = 3015,
wkbTinZM = 3016,
}
```

Comment: Perfect, after seeing that list I realised I had it all along but didn't cop it. Using help(ogr) all the data types were printed.

Comment: @Clubdebambos yep, that is another way!

Answer (score 7):

If you need to determine the type in code, use the `ogr.wkb*` constants as per @iant's answer.

Alternatively, if you just want to print out the type, you can use the `ogr.GeometryTypeToName` function.

```
print ogr.GeometryTypeToName(lyr_def.GetGeomType())
```

e.g

```
In [1]: from osgeo import ogr

In [2]: print ogr.GeometryTypeToName(ogr.wkbPoint)
Point

In [3]: print ogr.GeometryTypeToName(ogr.wkbPolygon)
Polygon

In [4]: print ogr.GeometryTypeToName(ogr.wkbLineString)
Line String
```

Answer (score 3):

It will return one of the constants on [this page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr__core_8h.html#a800236a0d460ef66e687b7b65610f12a) which judging from [this email](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-June/036422.html) you can refer to directly in your code, e.g.:

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("FileGDB")

gdb = r"C:\Users\******\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
ds = driver.Open(gdb, 0)
input_lyr_name = "Birmingham_Burglaries_2016"
lyr = ds.GetLayerByName(input_lyr_name)
# access the schema info
lyr_def = lyr.GetLayerDefn()
lyr_type = lyr_def.GetGeomType()
if lyr_type == ogr.wkbPolygon or lyr_type == ogr.wkbMultiPolygon:
    print "Polygon"
elif lyr_type == ogr.wkbPoint:
    print "Point"
```