# Is there an OGR is_line method?

Tags: python, geometry, ogr

Following on from [GDAL/OGR Geometry Type Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245936/gdal-ogr-geometry-type-python), what is the best way to determine if a vector geometry is any kind of line or point or whatever?

For example, I'm using this technique at the moment,

```
# check geom type is supported
vector_lyr = vector_ds.GetLayer()
ftr = vector_lyr.GetNextFeature()
geom = ftr.GetGeometryRef()
geom_type = geom.GetGeometryType()

if geom_type in (ogr.wkbLineString, ogr.wkbMultiLineString):
    do_line_stuff()
elif geom_type in (ogr.wkbPoint, ogr.wkbMultiPoint):
    do_point_stuff()
else:
    raise NotImplementedError(
        'Geometry Type {} is not supported'.format(geom.GetGeometryName()))
```

but it feels like it doesn't cover all geometry types. What if it's a curve, or a ring, or a geometry collection? Should I just list all the possible types in the if statements above, or is there a better way? There doesn't seem to be a catch-all is_line() method.

Comment: Do you need to find and process only lines, or you want to separate all geometries and do different things with each of them?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239289/gdal-ogr-python-getgeomtype-method-returns-integer-what-is-the-matching-geo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no - you have to write your own.